# React Router // redirect to dashboard when logged in

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react app and I would like the user to be redirected to the `'/dashboard'` when logged in and not the home route `'/'`. I have accomplished this with the `'/login'` route, but cannot get it to do the same for the `'/'` home route.

Any help or insight would be appreciated

occasionally when playing around I get the infinite loop error from React

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import ProtectedRoute from "./Utils/ProtectedRoute";
import PublicRoutes from "./Utils/PublicRoute";
import { AuthState, onAuthUIStateChange } from "@aws-amplify/ui-components";
import store from "./store";
import { userLogIn, userLogOut } from "./Actions/userActions";
import NavBar from "./Components/NavBar";
import Home from "./Screens/Home";
import AmplifySignUp from "./Components/AmplifyLogIn";
import Dashboard from "./Screens/Dashboard";

const Routes = (props) => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userState = useSelector((s) => s.user);

  useEffect(() => {
    return onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
      setAuthState(nextAuthState);
      setUser(authData);
    });
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (AuthState.SignedIn && user) {
      dispatch(userLogIn(user.attributes.email));
    }
  }, [user]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (authState !== AuthState.SignedIn) {
      dispatch(userLogOut());
    }
  }, [user]);

  // check auth

  
  const isAuth = async () => {
    try {
      const status = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    
        
        return status.username;
  
    } catch (err) {}
  };

//   Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
//     .then((user) => {
//       console.log(user.username)
//       setUserName(prevState => {
//           if(prevState !== user.username){
//               return user.username
//           }else {return prevState}
//       } 
//     )
//     })
    
//     .catch((err) => console.log(err));

 

  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          {userName ? <Redirect from='/' to="/dashboard" /> : <Home />}
        </Route>

        <Route path="/login">
          {authState === AuthState.SignedIn && user ? (
            <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
          ) : (
            <AmplifySignUp />
          )}
        </Route>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" user={user}>
          <Dashboard />
        </ProtectedRoute>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

#### ProtectedRoutes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const ProtectedRoutes = ({user, children, ...rest }) => {
  console.log(user && user)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() => {
        return user ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to='/'
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

On this line...

```js
{userName ? <Redirect from='/' to="/dashboard" /> : <Home />}
```

You're not updating the `username` state with the currently authenticated user, hence the dashboard redirect never happens.

#### Possible Solution

- Add a function to get the currently authenticated user
- Add a `useEffect` hook to update the `username` state with the returned user

##### Code

```
const getAuthenticatedUser = async () => {
  try {
    const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    return {
      user,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  const { user, error } = await getAuthenticatedUser();

  if (!error) {
    setUsername(user.username);
  }
}, []);
```